# Ubuntu machines cannot connect to each other on the same network

Tags: networking, server, ssh, firewall, iptables

I'm having trouble with Ubuntu machines not cooperating on my home network. The network structure is VERY simple. It's simply two Ubuntu machines (one running XBMCbuntu on 14.04, the other Ubunutu Server 14.04.03) connected by ethernet to a DD-WRT router with WiFi capability that connects a windows laptop.

My problem is that the Linux machines don't want to talk to eachother. XBMCbuntu (we'll call him hostA) can ping to/from the windows machines and I can SSH into hostA from the windows machines no problem. Ubuntu Server (hostB) can do the same. HOWEVER, hostA cannot ping/SSH hostB nor vis versa.

HostA trying to ping HostB

```
sebastien@hostA:~$ ping 192.168.1.148
PING 192.168.1.148 (192.168.1.148) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.101 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.101 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.101 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 192.168.1.148 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 4022ms
pipe 3
sebastien@hostA:~$ ping hostB
PING degroofserver (192.168.1.148) 56(84) bytes of data.
From hostA (192.168.1.101) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From hostA (192.168.1.101) icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From hostA (192.168.1.101) icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- hostB ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 4023ms
pipe 3
```

HostB trying to ping HostA results in the same. They can resolve the IP address but not the MAC address:

Here's hostA's arp -a

```
router (192.168.1.1) at 20:4e:7f:8e:00:91 [ether] on eth0
hostB (192.168.1.148) at <incomplete> on eth0
windows1 (192.168.1.110) at e0:b9:a5:fc:3e:e8 [ether] on eth0
```

And hostB's arp -a

```
windows1 (192.168.1.110) at e0:b9:a5:fc:3e:e8 [ether] on p1p1
hostA (192.168.1.101) at <incomplete> on p1p1
router (192.168.1.1) at 20:4e:7f:8e:00:91 [ether] on p1p1
```

HostA's ifconfig eth0

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr bc:5f:f4:fb:0a:ce
          inet addr:192.168.1.101  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::be5f:f4ff:fefb:ace/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:16
```

HostB's inconfig p1p1

```
p1p1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 8c:89:a5:e6:d9:c5
          inet addr:192.168.1.148  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::8e89:a5ff:fee6:d9c5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1956 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:676 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:486677 (486.6 KB)  TX bytes:102329 (102.3 KB)
```

Neither machines have iptables rules or active ufw. I've tried hard rebooting the router but this is a Layer 2 problem rather than layer 3 so nothing changed.

Comment: Why do both `hostA` and `hostB` have `arp` entries for `windows1`? I suspect that your network configuration is not "VERY simple". How is your "DD-WRT router " configured?

Comment: I'm guessing they have ARP entries because I'm SSHing into them from my windows laptop and I've been pinging the other machines on the network. My router has static addresses for the Linux machines to allow for portforwarding but that's it.